# SQL GROUP BY and COUNT with multiple columns

Tags: sql

I know I'm just making a simple error somewhere, but I can't figure it out. I'm sure this is beyond easy.

I have a table with user ids, names, and a profile. I'm trying to count the number of users with each profile, and group them by the profile. Below is a sample of fake data.

[image]

This is the kind of output I'm looking for:

[image]

Below are a few simplified versions of what I tried so far:

```
select UserID, Name, Profile 
from test_db
group by profile
```

Another attempt:

```
select UserID, Name, Profile, count(Profile)
from test_db
group by profile, UserID, Name
```

Neither give me what I'm looking for. I just get a long list of rows and for the count they just all have a 1 by them. I know I'm making it harder than it needs to be.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? (mysql, redshift, microsoft sql server, postgres, oracle, mariadb, snowflake, teradata, etc)?

Comment: Sorry. I should have clarified. This is MS Sql server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` and `COUNT()` window functions:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t.rn = 1 THEN t.Profile END Profile,
       CASE WHEN t.rn = 1 THEN t.counter END counter,
       t.User_ID,
       t.Name
FROM (
  SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Profile ORDER BY Name) rn,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Profile) counter
  FROM tablename t
) t
ORDER BY t.Profile, t.rn
```

I used the column `Name` to sort the rows in each `Profile`, but you can use any other column by making the change inside the `OVER` clause of `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried this solution too, and it worked great! I really appreciate your response and explanation.

Comment: @subzeroLV the results of the answer that you accepted are not like the expected output in your question.

Comment: You're right. I changed my vote, as the solution you gave was exactly what I asked for. I will say that both solutions suited my needs however. I should be more careful in selecting which solution best fit my needs.

Answer (score 3):

Chances are whatever RDBMS you are using supports window functions which you'll need for getting counts in an unaggregated result set like this.

```
 SELECT UserID
     ,Name
     ,Profile
     ,Count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Profile)
 FROM test_db
 ORDER BY Profile;
```

That won't give you blanks for repeating `Profile` and `Count` columns, but that's not really a thing that RDBMS's do so this is probably as close as you get.

You'll notice there is no `GROUP BY` here. You don't want to GROUP BY anything since you want the same number of records outputted as you put in. That `Count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Profile)` will group records by distinct `Profile` value and then give you a count for each group/partition.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much! This worked perfectly!

Comment: Thank you JNevill! I did change my vote for forpas' solution as it provided exactly what my expected output was. Yours worked too, and was less code. I appreciate you both!